# What is the proper way of using brackets and periods in quotes?

Tags: quotes, periods, square-brackets

I'm writing an essay. I know that I can alter or add words by using square brackets. However, I'm not sure if changing a case of a single letter applies to that rule. I didn't actually use square brackets in the past, so I'm not completely sure about it.

I have this direct quote: “Sometimes that meant we kept things from you, lied to you. Yes, in many ways we fooled you.”

I'm planning to write it likes this. Miss Emily shares that “[s]ometimes that meant we kept things from you, lied to you. Yes, in many ways we fooled you.” This is without an in-text citation, for example.

Should the period be outside of the quotes or inside?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If 'admits' applies, I'd use it as a quotative verb (with a colon) and keep the capital s. I can't see any justification for not including the final period as part of the quote, and I'm sure that many 'outside the inverted commas' fans would agree in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> [In US English, the full stop is usually placed inside the closing
>   quotation mark in this sentence. In British English, it is
>   usually placed outside.](http://www.betterwritingskills.com/articles/quotation-marks.txt)

[This other link also elaborates on different types of punctuation marks and whether they belong inside quotations.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-quotation-marks)

Generally, I would only put periods inside of quotation marks if they are part of the quote (i.e. If the quote is a full sentence). If I want to continue with the sentence after quoting or if the original code didn't contain a period, I would place the full stop outside of the quotation marks.

Comment: The period is included in the quotes and thank you for the clarification.